# Sharing on LinkedIn doesn't work / Problem with LinkedIn Page Inspector

Tags: linkedin-api, share

We run a website from where users can share pages on LinkedIn using the basic sharing URL `https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=https://THE_URL`.

This worked without any problems for years, yet recently we are facing problems that we cannot explain. Some of our URLs can be shared, while others, pointing to very similar pages, fail.

All of our sharable pages are served from the same infrastructure, same servers, same setup, same TLS certificate, rendered from the same application, etc.

As an example, I attached screenshots for two pages, which are basically identical, except from a few very small details.

While https://open.sap.com/courses/fg1 can be shared,

- Screenshot: [A "Create a Post" widget on LinkedIn with correct page preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMFxm.png)

the almost identical page https://open.sap.com/courses/fg1-1 can *not* be shared, the sharing widget shows an error:

- Screenshot: [A "Create a Post" widget on LinkedIn with error message in preview area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbrXC.png)

Additionally: since a while, both pages - fg1 as well as fg1-1 - *cannot* be opened in the [LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) - this worked earlier, there was no notable change on our side.

The error message in the post inspector says (for the page where actual sharing in the widget *works*):

**Ingestion Feedback**

```
Error   We encountered a server error while trying to inspect the URL.
```

**URL redirect trail**

```
1   0 undefined https://open.sap.com/courses/fg1
```

Summarizing: I am quite confident that this is not an issue caused by our infrastructure or the application - otherwise I would expect that *all* pages resulted in the same error when sharing.

Does anyone else face this issue or did so in the past and found a solution?

*Note:* it feels a bit odd to post this question here instead of filing a support ticket, but I was told that this would be the way to reach out.

Comment: Also having this problem, were you eventually able to find a fix?

Comment: Sorry, nothing yet. We're thinking of a way to inspect the incoming requests from LinkedIn on our side. I'll keep this updated if we find something.

Comment: We're having a similar issue, though the Post Inspector says that the URL returns a blank page. So, in almost a year, LinkedIn hasn't helped.